# Why does Highcharts div/chart extend past parent div?

Tags: html, css, highcharts

I have roughly the following markup:

```
<div id="container">
    <p>Title</p>
    <div id="chart1"></div>
    <p>Title 2</p>
    <div id="chart2"></div>
</div>
<p>Some footer text</p>
```

I render Highcharts to both 'chart' divs and for some reason chart2 is extending outside the bounds of container and I can't figure out why.

Here is a sample http://jsfiddle.net/9udgz5pp/ - pardon the huge configuration mess for the chart, I simply 'exported' the rendered settings from the browser console since the charts are generically built in javascript and I don't have the exact/clean markup to paste into jsfiddle.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to change `.view` class value

```
.views {
    background-color: red;
    /*height: 320px;*/
    /*padding-left: 40px;*/
    padding: 10px 35px;
    position: static;
    text-align: center;
    width: 380px;
}
```

Hope it will helps you.